# How to organize the top 10 frequent values in an array from greatest to least?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a homework that is called Lottery Statistics for PowerBall numbers. The PowerBall numbers were created into a text file. Before I explain my problem, a powerball has 5 numbers ranging from 1-69 and a sixth number being the BAll which is a number from 1-26. First thing I did in my program was to create an array to pass all the values from the file, then I separated the 5 powers in one array and the BALL in another. Now the issue is that I have been trying to figure out how would I find the top 10 common numbers in the array holding the powers and for the array holding the balls.

Attempting to solve it I used a frequency function and tried to compare the frequency for each value in the array, but ended up getting how many times each appeared in random order. I had in mind using a sort algorithm, but it would not work, since I'm trying to display the number and its frequency, and a sort algorithm would only help me display the frequency rather than the number and frequency in order.

For reference the values I used were:

```
39  12  21  23  67  6
33  43  60  59  15  4
25  16  32  49  19  4
54  50  21  64  68  4
44  62  20  37  16  12
66  52  50  24  25  5
10  53  50  63  14  21
67  30  34  16  53  21
69  36  45  47  18  14
45  5   59  55  50  14
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//Function prototype.
void powerValues(int [10][6], int [10], int [10][5]);
int frequency26(int [10], int);
int frequency69(int [][5], int);

int main()
{
    int num[10][6];
    int powerBall26[10];
    int powerBall69[10][5];

    //Function to store values from file in corresponding variable.
    powerValues(num, powerBall26, powerBall69);


    //Trying to find most frequent numbers to list top 10 common ones.
    for(int i = 1; i <= 69; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            if(frequency69(powerBall69, i) > frequency69(powerBall69, 1))
            {
                cout << i << " " << frequency69(powerBall69, i) << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

//This function grabs numbers from file to save numbers separately into two arrays.
//One array for powers(1-69) and other one for the powerBall(1-26).
void powerValues(int num[10][6], int powerBall26[10], int powerBall69[10][5])
{
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("lotteryNumbers.txt");

    //Passing values from file into temp array.
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
       {
          inFile >> num[i][k];
       }
    }

   //This loop stores the 6th power(AKA PowerBall) in array.
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       powerBall26[i] = num[i][5];
   }

   //This loop stores the first 5 powers in array.
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
       {
           powerBall69[i][j] = num[i][j];
       }
   }

   inFile.close();
}

//Calculates frequency of a number(1-26) in powerBall26.
int frequency26(int powerBall26[10], int value)
{
    int freq = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(powerBall26[i] == value)
           freq++;
    }

     return freq;
}

//Calculates frequency of a number(1-69) in powerBall69.
int frequency69(int powerBall69[][5], int value)
{
    int freq = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(powerBall69[i][j] == value)
                freq++;
        }
    }

    return freq;
}
```

I was expecting to get an output of 50: 4, 16: 3, 21: 2, 25: 2, 45: 2, 53: 2, and so on. Instead as mentioned before I ended up getting value of frequency for each number unorganized based on frequency.

Comment: Your instincts are correct. This has nothing to do with sorting, at least initially. Start by implementing the task of how many times the number "1" appears. Why, that's so easy! Initialize a counter to 0, loop over all numbers, each time you see "1", increment the counter. Now, extend that to all 69 values. Why, that's so easy! Instead of one counter, you have an array of 69 counters, and your loop simply increments the appropriate value in the counter array, at the end you have an array of how many times each number appears, and you sort *that* by value. Now do the same for the powerball.

Comment: I was able to pass the value of appearance from 1-69 into an array holding its frequency in order. However, once I sort the array with the frequency, how would I be able to tell which frequency belongs to which number, since the position will end up being switch around.

Comment: Create a record, a struct or a class, containing two fields: the value, and the count. Initialize an array of these records, from your computed counters. Sort the entire array, by the count value. Mission accomplished.

Comment: How would you do it with pencil and paper? Write code that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still struggling with how to get the top 10 most frequent numbers for both the lottery numbers and the powerball, then continuing from Sam's comment, you can use a simple `struct` (or `pair`, etc..) to coordinate the lottery numbers 1-69 with their frequency of occurrence in your input (and the same for the powerball). You could even use a 2D array of 2-`int` per-row for that matter, but using a struct probably provides a bit more readable implementation because it allows you to use the member names (e.g. `num` and `count`) rather than indexes `0` or `1`.

A simple `struct` is all you need to handle mapping the number frequency for each number in a way that will allow you to later sort preserving the relationship between the frequency and the number it is associated with, e.g.

```
struct freq {
    int num, count;     /* struct capturing number & count */
};
```

Rather than using fundamental types for your arrays, consider using the C++ container library [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which will make the container member functions for `array` such as the begin and end iterators, swap and the like available as well as allowing the array to be used with the `algorithm` library for [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) by simply passing the `.begin()` and `.end()` iterators along with a compare expression.

Regardless, you declare an array with 69 elements for your lottery number frequency tracking and an array with 26 elements for your powerball tracking. Using the `array` from the containers library you could do:

```
#define NMAX 69   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define BMAX 26
...
    std::array<freq, NMAX> nfreq;   /* array of struct for number frequency */
    std::array<freq, BMAX> bfreq;   /* array of struct for ball frequency */
```

To initialize each of the arrays, just store the sequential numbers from 1-69 as the `.num` member and set each `.count` member zero, (and 1-26 for the ball frequency array) e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < NMAX; i++)  /* initialize number freq array */
        nfreq[i].num = i + 1, nfreq[i].count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < BMAX; i++)  /* initialize ball freq array */
        bfreq[i].num = i + 1, bfreq[i].count = 0;
```

(**note:** how the `.num` member is initialized as `i + 1` rather than just `i` to accommodate the fact that your indexes will be 0-68, while you need your stored numbers to be 1-69.)

Now read all your data from your file. You don't need to store it anywhere (unless you have additional needs for it), you just need to set the frequency of each number and powerball. So you can simply read in a loop, use the first 5 numbers in each line to increment the count in your lottery number frequency array `nfreq` and the last number in each line to do the same for the powerball frequency array `bfreq` (ball frequency). For example:

```
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);      /* open filename given by 1st argument */
    /* validations omitted */
    while (getline (f, s)) {        /* read each line/fill freq arrays */
        std::stringstream ss (s);   /* create stringstream from line */
        size_t i = 0;               /* initialize counter zero */
        int tmp;                    /* tmp value to hold int read */
        while (i < NVAL && ss >> tmp)       /* read up to NVAL numbers */
            nfreq[tmp - 1].count++, i++;    /* increment nfreq count */
        if (i < NVAL) {     /* validate all number values read */
            std::cerr << "error: less than " << NVAL << "values read.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (!(ss >> tmp)) { /* validate ball value read */
            std::cerr << "error: no powerball value read.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        bfreq[tmp - 1].count++;     /* increment ball freq count */
    }
```

All that remains is sorting each of the arrays `nfreq` and `bfreq` by the `.count` member in descending order and then outputting the top 10 for each (or until the `.count` is `0`). Making use of [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) all you need to do is write an expression to compare the elements of each of the arrays and then pass that along with the start and end iterators for each array to `std::sort` and it will do the rest. The expression can either be a standard comparison as shown in the example provided at the link above, or you can use a short custom function of your own (or lamba function inline with the call to `std::sort`).

In your case it is probably just as easy to write one compare function, otherwise you will essentially duplicate the same code as the lamba in each call to sort. While not necessary, you can choose how you want the numbers displayed for the cases where the frequency for each of the numbers is the same. The compare function below sorts by `.count` (descending) and then if the `.count` is equal by `.num` (descending). It's completely up to you, e.g.

```
/* compare freq by count and if equal by num (descending) */
bool compare (const freq &a, const freq &b)
{
    if (a.count != b.count)
        return a.count > b.count;
    else
        return a.num > b.num;
}
```

Then since the container library `array` was used, passing the begin and end iterators to `std::sort` along with the compare function is as easy as:

```
    std::sort (nfreq.begin(), nfreq.end(), compare);
```

(do the same for `bfreq`)

Then just output the first 10 elements of the sorted arrays and you are done. Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

#define NVAL 5      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NMAX 69
#define BMAX 26
#define NTOP 10

struct freq {
    int num, count;     /* struct capturing number & count */
};

/* compare freq by count and if equal by num (descending) */
bool compare (const freq &a, const freq &b)
{
    if (a.count != b.count)
        return a.count > b.count;
    else
        return a.num > b.num;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1-argument available for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficnent input\nusage: " << argv[0]
                << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string s;
    std::array<freq, NMAX> nfreq;   /* array of struct for number frequency */
    std::array<freq, BMAX> bfreq;   /* array of struct for ball frequency */

    for (int i = 0; i < NMAX; i++)  /* initialize number freq array */
        nfreq[i].num = i + 1, nfreq[i].count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < BMAX; i++)  /* initialize ball freq array */
        bfreq[i].num = i + 1, bfreq[i].count = 0;

    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);      /* open filename given by 1st argument */
    if (!f.good()) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << argv[1] << "'.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline (f, s)) {        /* read each line/fill freq arrays */
        std::stringstream ss (s);   /* create stringstream from line */
        size_t i = 0;               /* initialize counter zero */
        int tmp;                    /* tmp value to hold int read */
        while (i < NVAL && ss >> tmp)       /* read up to NVAL numbers */
            nfreq[tmp - 1].count++, i++;    /* increment nfreq count */
        if (i < NVAL) {     /* validate all number values read */
            std::cerr << "error: less than " << NVAL << "values read.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (!(ss >> tmp)) { /* validate ball value read */
            std::cerr << "error: no powerball value read.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        bfreq[tmp - 1].count++;     /* increment ball freq count */
    }

    /* sort number frequency array of struct by count descending */
    std::sort (nfreq.begin(), nfreq.end(), compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < NTOP && nfreq[i].count; i++)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << nfreq[i].num << " : " 
                    << nfreq[i].count << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    /* sort ball frequency array of struct by count descending */
    std::sort (bfreq.begin(), bfreq.end(), compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < NTOP && bfreq[i].count; i++)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << bfreq[i].num << " : " 
                    << bfreq[i].count << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your data in the file `dat/pwrball.txt`, the frequency for the lottery numbers followed by the powerball values (stopped when the frequency was zero) would be:

```
$ ./bin/pwrballnumfreq dat/pwrball.txt
50 : 4
16 : 3
67 : 2
59 : 2
53 : 2
45 : 2
25 : 2
21 : 2
69 : 1
68 : 1

 4 : 3
21 : 2
14 : 2
12 : 1
 6 : 1
 5 : 1
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. If you wanted to use a lamda function in-line with the call to `std::sort` instead of writing a separate `compare` function, you could do the following:

```
    std::sort (nfreq.begin(), nfreq.end(), [](freq a, freq b) {
        if (a.count != b.count)
            return a.count > b.count;
        else
            return a.num > b.num;
    });
```

Which does the exact same thing. (personally, in this case, the `compare` function probably saves a few lines of code)

Answer (score 0):

Answering 3 year old homework question.

You can use also more modern C++ elements from the std::lib.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

// Test code
int main() {
    // Open document amd check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream ifs{ "r:\\lotteryNumbers.txt" }; ifs) {

        // Read all numbers
        std::vector<int> all{ std::istream_iterator<int>(ifs),{} };

        // Counters
        std::unordered_map<int, std::size_t> counter1{};
        std::unordered_map<int, std::size_t> counter2{};

        // Count balls
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < all.size(); ++i)
            if (i % 6 < 5)
                counter1[all[i]]++;  // Normal balls
            else
                counter2[all[i]]++;  // Powerballs

        // Results:
        std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>> top1(10);
        std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>> top2(10);

        // Get the tops
        std::partial_sort_copy(counter1.begin(), counter1.end(), top1.begin(), top1.end(),
            [](const std::pair<int, std::size_t >& p1, const std::pair<int, size_t>& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; });
        std::partial_sort_copy(counter2.begin(), counter2.end(), top2.begin(), top2.end(),
            [](const std::pair<int, std::size_t >& p1, const std::pair<int, size_t>& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; });

        // Show output
        for (const auto& [ball1, count1] : top1) if (count1) std::cout << "Ball: " << ball1 << " \t Count: " << count1 << '\n'; std::cout << '\n';
        for (const auto& [ball2, count2] : top2) if (count2) std::cout << "PowerBall: " << ball2 << " \t Count: " << count2 << '\n'; std::cout << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n\n";
}
```